# How to Center a button using Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

friend!
I am create a video list.
I use bootstrap grid system create it.
This is my code
I want to play button vertically and horizontally centere in the middle thumbnail.
How to modify the code?

```css
.test {
    width: 100%;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    position: relative;
}
.quick-img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.kkk {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 25%;
    left: 45%;
    font-size: 60px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.static.runoob.com/libs/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 ">
            <div class="test">
                <a href="//google.com">
                    <img class="quick-img" src="http://imgs.aixifan.com/content/2017_10_02/1509609180.png" />
                    <button class="kkk glyphicon glyphicon-play"></button>
                </a>

                <h2 style=" word-break: break-all;
      word-wrap: break-word;">title test</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 ">
            <div class="test">
                <a href="//google.com">
                    <img class="quick-img" src="http://imgs.aixifan.com/content/2017_10_02/1509609180.png" />
                    <button class="kkk glyphicon glyphicon-play"></button>
                </a>

                <h2 style=" word-break: break-all;
      word-wrap: break-word;">title test</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 ">
            <div class="test">
                <a href="//google.com">
                    <img class="quick-img" src="http://imgs.aixifan.com/content/2017_10_02/1509609180.png" />
                    <button class="kkk glyphicon glyphicon-play"></button>
                </a>

                <h2 style=" word-break: break-all;
      word-wrap: break-word;">title test</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

HI
friend!
I am create a video list.
I use bootstrap grid system create it.
This is my code
I want to play button vertically and horizontally centere in the middle thumbnail.
How to modify the code?

Comment: you want on the thumbnail?

Comment: You want the button to be aligned in the middle of both the thumbnails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.test a { display: block; position: relative; }

button.kkk { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to your css:

```
.kkk  
{
    padding-top:50px;
}
```

Comment: simple and elegant solution